# Webpack 3 and CommonsChunkPlugin - Exclude specific entry point from requiring Vendor

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm working on a large piece of business software which is slowly being migrated to use Webpack on all pages. I want to start incorporating some webpack-bundled helper typescript code into pages which haven't yet started using webpack - they include scripts the old-fashioned way.

Here are the relevant parts of the config:

```
entry: {
    vendor: [
        // All vendor scripts go here
    ],

    // All entry points for 'webpack' pages...

    // A special entry point that I want to inject into non-webpack pages
    es5Compatibility: [
        'Utility/ES5Compatibility.ts'
    ]
},

// ...

output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'Scripts/bundle'),
    filename: '[name].[chunkhash].bundle.js',
    chunkFilename: '[id].chunk.js'
},
plugins: [
    // ...

    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
        name: 'vendor',
        minChunks: Infinity
    })

    // This should NOT get injected into non-webpack pages, as all of the
    // vendor dependencies already exist there
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        chunks: ['vendor'],
        template: 'bundleTemplate.ejs',
        inject: false,
        filename: '_VendorBundle.html'
    }),

    // This should get injected into non-webpack pages WITHOUT requiring
    // the above bundle to be included
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        chunks: ['es5Compatibility'],
        template: 'bundleTemplate.ejs',
        inject: false,
        filename: '_ES5CompatibilityBundle.html'
    }),

    // ...
    new webpack.HashedModuleIdsPlugin(),
]
```

The problem is, when the `_ES5CompatibilityBundle.html` is included in a page without the `VendorBundle.html`, I get the following Javascript error as Webpack expects that the vendor bundle was included:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: webpackJsonp is not defined
```

How can I tell Webpack to bundle the ES5 compatibility bundle as a 'self-contained' bundle, while retaining the commons chunk functionality for the webpack pages?